# SimpleXML Help Needed

Tags: php, simplexml

I am able to parse the data I want but I'm having issues trying to format the data the way I want to.

**XML Data:**

```
<home>
<data number="1" name="John" color="Red"/>
<data number="2" name="Jim" color="Blue"/>
<data number="3" name"Bob" color="Black"/>
</home>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
foreach ($xml->home->data as $info){
$number = $info['number'];
$name = $info['name'];
$color = $info['color'];
mysql insert into database code here
}
```

So from here what I want to do is combine each entry into a single variable so I can insert it into my database.

I'd like to insert this into the database like below:

```
1. John(Red)
2. Jim(Blue)
3. Bob(Black)
```

And insert it just like that as one entry/row instead of each line being inserted separately/new row for each XML Data found.(Hopefully that makes sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Requested solution**

```
$str = "";
foreach ($xml->home->data as $info){
    $str .= $info['number'] . " " . $info['name']. "(".$info['color'].") ";
}
//insert into database using whatever method you're using. i.e. PDO.
```

**Alternative soltutions**

Alright, why don't you put it all into an array, serialize it (for future use) and then base64_encode to make it database-safe? I know you didn't specifically ask for this, but it'd definitely be a better solution.

```
$insert = array();
foreach ($xml->home->data as $info){
    $insert[$info['number']] = $info['name']."(".$info['color'].")";
    $insert = base64_encode(serialize($insert));
}
//insert into database using whatever method you're using. i.e. PDO.
```

You could also use:

```
$insert[] = array("id" => $info['number'], "name" => $info['name'], "colour" = > $info['color']);
```

In this case, you can interate through the array to search easier but cannot access the specific person via their ID, if you'd like that instead, use this:

```
$insert[$info['number']] = array("name" => $info['name'], "colour" = > $info['color']);
```

This way, you can pull all the data back out of the database and decode and unseralise like this:

```
seralize(base64_decode($array));
```

And access each user by their ID via the indexes, for example (in the first case), `$array[1]` would contain: `John(Red)`

For the second example, use `$array[0]` to get `John(Red)` and in the third example, you can use `array[1]` again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help on this. Is there a way to take all of the data items and put them into one array before inserting that into a mysql data base? For example $insert would have the data 1.John(Red), 2. Jim(Blue), 3. Bob(Black)

Comment: That's precisely what my example code does. It puts everything inside the `$insert` variable and encodes it all, ready to be put into the database. I touched on this in my answer, but just insert the contents of `$insert` and store it somewhere (such as a database) and then when you get it back via `seralize(base64_decode($array));` you can use `$array[1]` to access the string "John(Red)" and `$array[3]` to get the string "Bob(Black)". I will also update my answer with another solution which will split the name from the colour in the array as well.

Comment: I'm looking to have one array to have John(Red) and Bob(Black) together. Is that possible? When I tried this it still created separate rows in the Database for each array. I want one row in the database with all of the XML data.

Comment: What do you mean? Everything is stored inside the `$insert` array. Do you just want a string that says "1. John(Red) 2. Jim(Blue)"?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. Sorry I'm kind of new to PHP so I'm probably not doing the best job of explaining things haha =)

Comment: Thanks for all the help on this. It's almost perfect now =)...Right now it is inserting 3 rows into the database. The first row has 1. John(Red), the second row has 1. John(Red) 2. Jim(Blue), and the third row has 1. John(Red) 2. Jim(Blue)3. Bob(Black). The third row is perfect but I'm looking to do this without having it insert the first two rows in the database. Is there a way to only insert into the database after it has all of the data in the string instead of doing the insert three times? Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I figured that part out by putting the insert statement outside of the for loop =).....Thanks again for all your time and help on this. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah oops, that's my mistake! Good job on sorting it out though. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you can:
- write an SQL & execute the insert
- create a stored procedure with 2 variables (name & color).

I prefer the usage of stored procedures because it saves the database the time needed to interpret the SQL since it already knows what it should be doing.

I would create a table with following specs:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA (
id_name VARCHAR,
color VARCHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (id_name))
```

Then write a stored procedure to call:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE storeKeys(IN var_name VARCHAR, IN var_color VARCHAR)
BEGIN INSERT INTO data(id_name, color) VALUES(@var_name, @var_color);
```

And then call it all from inside your PHP loop and just set the variables.

As a guide: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

If you have a lot of data to process you can increase the performance by creating a batch of query's.

I hope this helps